# Wire doesn't work between Uno & ESP32S & ESP8266

Tags: esp8266, esp32, wire-library

I think i've reached my limit. I can't get Wire to work between an Uno or ESP8266 or ESP32S. On the Uno I had them connected like SDA via Uno SDA -> ESP32 GPIO21 SCL via Uno SCL -> ESP32 GPIO22.

I also tried flipping them like this:

- SDA via Uno SDA -> ESP32 GPIO22
- SCL via Uno SCL -> ESP32 GPIO21

Connections are as follows:

- SDA via ESP32 GPIO21 -> ESP8266 GPIO4
- SCL via ESP32 GPIO22 -> ESP8266 GPIO5

I also tried flipping them, as follows:

- SDA via ESP32 GPIO21 -> ESP8266 GPIO5
- SCL via ESP32 GPIO22 -> ESP8266 GPIO4

I have present a 4.7 kOhm pull-up resistor from SDA and SCL to +3.3 V.

All these combinations led to nil result on I2C bus scanners. I tried 5 scanners and 3 Wire libs. I tried having the ESP32 as slave because I heard the ESP8266 won't work as slave. I know I'm doing something wrong but can't figure it out, I've been at it all day.

Comment: the esp8266 and the esp32 Wire library supports only master. so you can't make them communicate

Comment: That is unforturnate. I believe stickman is working on a lib that supports slave.

Comment: sorry, the esp Wire libraries support slave mode, but it is experimental and doesn't work in most cases

Comment: In https://github.com/espressif/arduino-esp32/tree/master/libraries/Wire/examples they provide examples of master, slave, and scan.